# Recently used an old script using Ngrok but now it doesnt work

Tags: python, ngrok

Basically I just booted up an older script that I made 1-2 months ago and which worked perfectly at the time, but now when I try to connect to the ngrok tunnel i get a 404 and a "Tunnel xxxx not found"

I have a non-paying user, which didn't use to be a problem and I cant see anywhere that they changed their terms of service and I can find the tunnel on the dashboard but not connect, any idea what is wrong and if they changed something?

I just booted an old super simple test script which also doesn't work, I can see the tunnel but it returns "Funnel xxxx not found" and server 404:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)   #starts ngrok when the app is run
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Running Flask on Google Colab!</h1>"
  
app.run()
```

Comment: Ngrok tunnels are temporary, have you started the tunnel up again?

Comment: Yeah just booted another script up, super simple see the edit, same thing